# Adding more than one buttons on headerRight in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native. Here I am trying to add two buttons on headerRight. I did add one button but I could not figure out how to put more than one. Something like this.
[image: two button icon]

I am using `react-navigaiton` and `react-navigation-header-buttons`.

This is how I added one button.

> mainScreen

```
headerRight: (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
                <Item
                    title={"Search"}
                    iconName={"md-search"}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log('Search')
                    }}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        ),
```

> CustomHeaderButton.js

```
import {HeaderButton, Item} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
const CustomHeaderButton = props => {
    return(
        <HeaderButton
            {...props}
            IconComponent={Ionicons}
            iconSize={23}
            color={'black'}
        />
    )
};
export default CustomHeaderButton;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. You should be able to simply add another `Item` with whatever title, icon, onPress functionality you want wrapped in the `HeaderButtons` component like this:

```
<HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
                <Item
                    title={"Search"}
                    iconName={"md-search"}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log('Search')
                    }}
                />
                <Item
                    title={"Other Button"}
                    iconName={"other-icon-name"}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log('The other header icon was pressed.')
                    }}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
```

You are able to nest multiple React elements within a React element, which is what this example uses. For instance, you can nest multiple `Text` elements inside of a `View`.

It looks like you are using the `react-navigation-header-buttons` package, here is their example with multiple header icons for your reference as well: https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons/blob/master/example/screens/UsageCustom.tsx